# Convert DOMTimeStamp to DATETIME in PHP

Tags: php, dom, w3c-geolocation

I want to convert [DOMTimeStamp](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#position_interface) from [Geolocation](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/) in PHP in order to save it in DATETIME in the database. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Show us a sample value and what you've tried so far

Comment: I don't have any example because I "must" save it in DOMTimeStamp in the database. I don't know how to convert it to DATETIME in PHP

Comment: did you reviewed this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089308/converting-domtimestamp-to-localized-hhmmss-mm-dd-yy-via-javascript

Comment: You can't echo it out to your screen?

Comment: @JasonOOO Yes. I'm using that function in JavaScript but I want to save the DOMTimeStamp in DATETIMe instead. To do that, I must convert it to DATETIME in PHP, like `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Comment: You could always hand the timestamp directly to the database... e.g. using MySQL's [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function.

Comment: Have you read http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php and http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php ?  The PHP manual is pretty well written and has good examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a just a timestamp in milliseconds. Just convert it to seconds and then use PHP's built in Date/Time functionality to convert it:

```
$timestamp = floor($domtimestamp / 1000); // Get seconds from milliseconds
$datetime = new DateTime('@'.$timestamp);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Your answer solved my issue :) Many thanks! I'll accept it as soon as I can