# IONIC 3 how to get current date/time from google servers for specific country?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on IONIC 3 app, I have a button When it is pressed, some informations about the user location are sent to firebase .. i want to send the current date/time too with the geolocation informations .. but not the device's date/time of course.

any help ?

this is my function to send informations :

```
addAgentCoords(){
this.gpsCoordsRef$.push({
  latitude: this.lat,
  longitude: this.long,
  accuracy: this.acc,
  altitude: this.alt,
  altitudeAccuracy: this.altacc,
  speed: this.spd
  //dateTime: ??   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var dd = d.getDate();
var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
var yy = d.getFullYear();
var myDateString = dd + '_' + mm + '_' + yy;
```

And change the last variable to anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to timestamp from geolocation plugin in a variable like **lat**
let us consider timestamp in **timestamp** variable

Then Try it

```
this.gpsCoordsRef$.push({
      latitude: this.lat,
      longitude: this.long,
      accuracy: this.acc,
      altitude: this.alt,
      altitudeAccuracy: this.altacc,
      speed: this.spd,
      dateTime: new Date(timestamp)  
    });
```

**Check converting timestamp to dateTime** [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089308/converting-domtimestamp-to-localized-hhmmss-mm-dd-yy-via-javascript)